# How to query android call log data with group by date

Tags: android, sqlite

I am querying call dates in call log database in android phone. After reading some articles, they said this needs to make some injection in my query method like this.

```
Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(
                    CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { CallLog.Calls.DATE},
                    "" + ") GROUP BY (" + CallLog.Calls.DATE,
                    null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
```

When I run my app and I got the following error message.

```
near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT date FROM calls WHERE ((() GROUP BY (date) AND ((type != 4)))) ORDER BY date DESC
```

Actually, I can't figure out how this query was built and why ((type !=4)) filter was appended to GROUP BY clause. I am currently using (compileSdkVersion 19, minSdkVersion 10 and targetSdkVersion 19). Is there any way to make raw query to Call Log Database because I want to write the query with my own to group dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), CallsQuery.CONTENT_URI, CallsQuery.PROJECTION, null, null,            CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

You can use the `DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER` which is `date DESC`

[public static final String DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER)

```
The default sort order for this table
Constant Value: `"date DESC"`
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the extra brackets from your query and change it as below:

```
   Cursor cursor =mActivity.getContentResolver().query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { CallLog.Calls.DATE},
            " GROUP BY " + CallLog.Calls.DATE,null,CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
```

Comment: I already tried it. But, it's not work. Because, the generated query contain WHERE clause.

Comment: @GrlsHu I tried your answer. But, it's not working. Still getting exception.